# No keyboard / mouse after Sysprep

Tags: windows-7, bios, sysprep

I've changed **mobo and CPU** on a computer.

Before change mobo and cpu I've `run sysprep.exe`.

When I start the computer, keyboard and mouse works fine in the bios but when windows is launched, there is a window which ask me to choose language but impossible to choose it because keyboard and mouse are not recognised.

How activate mouse and keyboard?

Comment: Have you writed for a couple minutes after your start it? IIRC it takes a bit of time for Windows to probe (all) the devices and set up the drivers again after a sysprep.

Comment: Btw what's the model of your new mobo?

Comment: I've wait like 5 minutes after start it. The new mobo is a Z170A from MSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motherboards based on the Z170 often no longer have an USB2 controller.  On older boards USB1/USB2 was present in the chipset and you could add extra chips for more USB2 or for USB3.

The Z170 series (and IIRC on all 1xx-series based boards) has changed this to a default USB3 controller. Until you add USB2 drivers these ports will **only** speak USB3.

That means no USB2 based keyboards or mice...

Solutions:

- Use a PS2 based keyboard (at least for installation).
- Slipstream USB3 drivers to the installation.
- Add USB3 to the drivers via [this tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility) from Microsoft.

Quoting the MS website:

Purpose

Windows 7* installation media doesn't include native driver support for USB 3.0, so during installation, when you get to the screen to select your preferred language, a keyboard or mouse connected to a USB 3.0 port does not respond.

This Windows 7 USB 3.0 Creator Utility automates the process to update a Windows 7 installation image to include USB 3.0 drivers.

Answer (score 0):

In the bios / advanced / OS configuration there is the following option "Enable USB configuration for windows 7". I choose that and it works.